# Can't save url shared with extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, ios-extensions

I want to use an extension to share an url with the host app. urlShareManager is a singleton in an embedded framework I use to communicate between the app and extension. When I call urlShareManager in Viewcontroller I can add urls. It doesn't work when I add urls with the extension. I stepped through the code line by line and it seems to save the url when adding one from the extension. Yet the only urls I can load are those saved with the host app viewcontroller. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

**urlShareManager**

```
 + (id)UrlShareManager
    {
        static UrlShare *urlShareManager = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            urlShareManager = [[self alloc] init];
    //        urlShareManager.urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        });

        return urlShareManager;
    }

    - (id)init
    {
        if (self = [super init])
        {
            self.urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            self.urlArray = [self loadURLS];
        }

        return self;

    }


    - (NSString *)getFileURL
    {
        NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.net.noizystudios.urlGroup"];
        NSURL *jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[containerURL.path stringByAppendingString:@"/urlData.dat"]];
        NSString *filePath = [jsonURL absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"Filepath: %@", filePath );
        return filePath;
    }

    - (void)addURL:(NSString *)url
    {
        self.urlArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSLog(@"URL STRING: %@", url);
        Bookmark *urlBookmark = [[Bookmark alloc]init];
        urlBookmark.urlString = url;
        [self.urlArray addObject:urlBookmark];
        [self saveURLS];
    }

    - (NSMutableArray *)loadURLS
    {
        NSString *path = [self getFileURL];
        NSMutableArray *url = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        url = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
        NSLog(@"URL array inhoud: %@", url);
        return url;
    }

    - (void)saveURLS
    {

        NSString *path = [self getFileURL];
        BOOL isSaved = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.urlArray toFile:path];
        NSLog (isSaved ? @"saved" : @"not saved");

    }



    @end
```

**Viewcontroller**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];


   UrlShare  *urlManager = [UrlShare UrlShareManager];
   [urlManager addURL:@"http://www.reddit.com"];
   articleListArray = [urlManager loadURLS];
   [self.tableView reloadData];   
}
```

**ActionRequestHandler**

```
- (void)doneWithResults:(NSDictionary *)resultsForJavaScriptFinalize 
{
               ...

                  NSString *url = resultsForJavaScriptFinalize[@"URL"];
                  UrlShare *urlManager = [UrlShare UrlShareManager];
                  [urlManager addURL:url];


                 ... 
                // Don't hold on to this after we finished with it.
                self.extensionContext = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read up about sandboxing and App Transport Security? And also on URL bookmark data?

Basically, for security reasons, the user has to specify files and URLs to open, and the OS knows your app is supposed to be able to open them then. If you want one app to transfer this permission to another app (and extensions are basically separate apps), you have to transfer bookmark data, which combines the permission and the URL.

Comment: I don't see what App Transport Security has to do with this. Passing the url, actually just an nsstring, to urlShareManager isn't the problem. Allow Arbitrary Loads is set to YES in info.plist.  
I'm using a shared container so sandboxing shouldn't be an issue? I can pass the data, I can even save it. I just can't seem to retrieve it.

Comment: Do you get any log messages on the console?

Comment: Okay, I found the bug.  In my viewcontroller I called [urlManager saveURLS] without adding an url. Because self.array of the urlShareManager singleton was always empty when I called the save method, it overwrote the previous urlData.dat file..